# Rails 3.1: Jbuilder rendering empty views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3.1, jbuilder

Trying to use Jbuilder to create some JSON views for my app, but the views are coming out empty.  Using the builder code in the console, however, works just fine.

Controller code:

```
@placements = Placement.all
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json
end
```

Jbuilder view (index.json.builder):

```
Jbuilder.encode do |json|
  json.array!(@placements) do |json, placement|
    json.id placement.id
    json.name placement.name
  end
end
```

Visiting `http://localhost:3000/placements.json` results in an empty page.  Removing the `respond_to` format block doesn't help.  If I use the following code in my controller, I get an output, but it's obviously not the Jbuilder output.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json {render json: @placements}
end
```

Has anyone else seen this problem?

Comment: Take a look at the logs, and make sure it's trying to render the right template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Robin - It was rendering the wrong template, but I had the wrong extension.  I was using `builder` instead of `jbuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove f

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json {render json: @placements}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Same [issue](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/issues/346) in **rails specs** with jbuilder 2.6.0  rails 5.0.0 and existed views.

Suggested in mentioned issue solutions:

Solved by adding render type with collection or resource

for example for `index` action replace:

```
render :index
```

with:

```
render :index, json: @collection
```

Or solved by configuring rspec like this:

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.render_views = true
end
```

Or

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionView::Rendering
end
```